# AWS ACM List Certificates UnknownOperationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-acm

We are trying to work with AWS ACM in us-east-1 region to automate the things.
Trying to follow [their doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_ListCertificates.html) and not getting too far with minimal ideas where to turn.

We get 404 and error `<UnknownOperationException/>` for everything that we send at it, even changing endpoint doesn't help.

Our API requests are validated using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 as they request.

Hope we are missing something obvious, or, if someone has some experience with this specific endpoint can lend some pointers - thank-you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend using the SDK. Those items in the docs are not query params, see the example request at the bottom. How are you computing the signature?

Comment: Hey @jordanm. We are using Postman currently to compute the signature and testing within Postman.